# excel macro application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the below code and get the error. The code is used to take a group of sigle items and group them and their individula corresponding values together.

`application-defined or object-defined error`
When the code reaches the line:
`.Range("B15:B" & LastRow).Formula = "=SUMIF(" & myrng1.Address & ",RC[-1]," & myrng2.Address & ")"

The error is with the middle section of the code `RC[-1]` If someone could please tell me what i shuld use in place of this, it would be of great assistance
`

The code is

```
Sub InventorySummerise()

Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Set myrng1 = Range("B2:B" & LastRow)
Set myrng2 = Range("D2:D" & LastRow) 
Cells(LastRow + 5, 2).Select
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("B15:B" & LastRow).Formula = "=SUMIF(" & myrng1.Address & ",RC[-1]," & myrng2.Address & ")"
End With

End Sub
```

Any help with what is wrong would be amazing, im at wits end with it

Thank you!

Comment: Which line is the code breaking on? I suspect it is the 4th line from the bottom. I am not sure if the formula you have entered is valid. `Dim` a string right before `.Range("B15:B" & ...` and set the string equal to the right hand side of the line starting with `.Range("B15:B" & ....` . Add a watch, copy the string, and then manually paste the formula into a cell and see if Excel gives you an error.

Comment: yeap sorry guys just fixed it up, so add a string and a watch ey? Are you sure thats going to work with the `=SUMIF`in there??

Comment: The String does not care if the formula is valid or not; a String is merely an array of characters. But the Formula Object within the Range Object does care if it is valid. A watch is just an easy way to be able to copy the value of the String and test it in Excel. I use this method a lot when I am testing complicated formulas in vba.

Comment: Expected: Identifer when i try to dim the RHS as a string

Comment: Hmmmm. Maybe try replace the `&`'s with `+`'s? At least for the String. Not sure if that would make a difference, its just that I personally always use `+` instead of `&`.

Comment: It is specifically highlighting `"=SUMIF("` regardless of & or +

Comment: So, I threw together something to test it, and your formula is giving me an error on your criteria input into the SUMIF function. Your criteria is RC[-1], and I believe it needs to be something like ">-1" or some sort of boolean statement.

Comment: I tried RC[>-1], sadly it made no difference

Comment: Sorry to be unclear, but I think its the `RC` that is messing you up. If you want it to only sum values greater than -1, you need to replace all of `RC[-1]` with `"">-1""`

Comment: Its not even getting to that part as its stil lhighlightsing the `"=SUMIF("` in `Dim "=SUMIF(" + myrng1.Address + ",>-1," + myrng2.Address + ")" As String`

Comment: Ah, you can't define a String that way. You have to do it in two steps. You would have to instantiate the String with `Dim temp As String` in one line and then in the next line initialize it with `temp = "=SUMIF...`

Comment: What is the value of `LastRow`?

Comment: Also Why make your code so complicated. As I mentioned in your last question, You can write

`Range("B3:" & Cells(LastRow, 2).Address(rowabsolute:=False, columnabsolute:=False))`

as

`Range("B3:B" & LastRow)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

two ways to get this done:

**One:**

```
'~~> change RC[-1] reference to A1 notation
'~~> so if you are putting formula in B15, RC[-1] is A15
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("B15:B" & LastRow).Formula = "=SUMIF(" & myrng1.Address & ",A15," & myrng2.Address & ")"
End With
```

**Two:**

```
'~~> As what Patrick said, use FormulaR1C1
'~~> Then change R1C1 address reference style for your ranges
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("B15:B" & LastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(" & myrng1.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & ",RC[-1]," & myrng2.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & ")"
End With
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use R1C1 formulas to normal Formula.

Should use `.Range("B15:B" & LastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "..."`

Try this:

```
Sub InventorySummerise()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim LastRow As Long, myrng1 As Range, myrng2 As Range
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Set myrng1 = Range("B3:" & Cells(LastRow, 2).Address(rowabsolute:=False, columnabsolute:=False))
    Set myrng2 = Range("D3:" & Cells(LastRow, 4).Address(rowabsolute:=False, columnabsolute:=False))

    With ThisWorkbook
        .Names("Range1").Delete
        .Names("Range2").Delete
        .Names.Add "Range1", myrng1
        .Names.Add "Range2", myrng2
        .Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B15:B" & LastRow + 5).Formula = "=SUMIF(Range1,RC[-1],Range2)"
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully It has been already resolved for you.  If that's not the case, error comes from the .range not recognize.  If activating workbook does not bother you, you could try the following:

```
Sub InventorySummerise()
Dim wtb As Workbook
Dim LastRow As Long
Set wtb = ThisWorkbook
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Set myrng1 = Range("B3:" & Cells(LastRow, 2).Address(rowabsolute:=False, columnabsolute:=False))
Set myrng2 = Range("D3:" & Cells(LastRow, 4).Address(rowabsolute:=False, columnabsolute:=False))
Cells(LastRow + 5, 2).Select
wtb.Activate
With Sheets("Sheet1")
.Range("B15:B" & LastRow).Formula = "=SUMIF(" & myrng1.Address & ",1," & myrng2.Address & ")"
End With
End Sub
```